# What module in the kernel that inform the DHCP client to start DHCP negotiation?

Tags: kernel, process, kernel-modules, dhcp

DHCP client is a process instead of kernel code. How the DHCP client know when to start sending DHCP discover message? Is it the IP module in the kernel that inform the DHCP client?

Answer (score 2):

The DHCP client daemon (`dhcpdc`, `dhclient`, etc) are programs that are started during the init process.  These programs are not always directly invoked by init, but rather the program that handles networking will do this when an interface is configured to use dhcp.

For example, `netctl` is one such program distros use to manage the networking interfaces.   This programs uses configuration files where you can specify a static address or dhcp (among other options).  If you have the configuration file setup to use dhcp, then when `netctl` is invoked by the init system, it will start the dhcp client to acquire an address.  When the dhcp client starts it will begin sending DHCPDISCOVER messages unless it has a recent lease, then it will instead DHCPREQUEST for the address in the leaase.

The kernel isn't really part of this process at all, except for the initial spawning of the init system main process (sysvinit/systemd/etc).  There will either be an init script that directly invokes a dhcp client or there will be a network managing service that handles that.

Comment: If netctl is invoked by init, then it is a process (user space). How do the netctl know when to start the DHCP client? It is not necessary to start the DHCP client at the start of the OS if there is nothing connected to the NIC.